# Generate option dynamic in gsp

Tags: grails

I'm trying to build generate dynamic select items in my GSP file. But somehow it's not doing the way I wanted, because it's giving me a ""?

The way I'm trying to build:

```
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="CHINESE">Chinese Food</option>
    <option value="JAPANESE">Japanese Food</option>
    <option value="KOREAN">Korean Food</option>
</select>
```

It's generating in a strange way with `""`

```
<select name="type" id="type">
    " <option value="CHINESE">Chinese Food</option><option value="JAPANESE">Japanese Food</option><option value="KOREAN">Korean Food</option>"
</select>
```

javascript code:

```
var foodTypes = '<%
    def f = "";
    food.type.FoodType?.values().each() {
        f +=  "<option value=\""+ it.name() +"\">" + it.description + "</option>";
    }
    out << f ;
    %>';

html += '<select name="type" id="type"> ' + foodTypes + ' </select>'
```

Or there is a way better?

Comment: Maybe you need to change your default encoding but watch to security issues

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do directly without javascript:

```
<g:select name="type" from="${food.type.FoodType?.values()}" value="${name}"
      optionKey="name" optionValue="description"/>
```

You can check:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

Or if you need the javascript you can do:

```
var foodTypes = '<%
def f = "";
food.type.FoodType?.values().each() {
    f +=  "<option value='${it.name()}'\>${it.description}</option>";
}
out << f ;
%>';

   html += '<select name="type" id="type"> ' + foodTypes + ' </select>'
```

Comment: You must try. But I think yes.

Comment: It worked to generate, but it didn't work because it's inside of javascript.

Comment: Why you need the javascript?

Comment: Because when I click on a button, javascript will create a dynamic form(`html += ...`) and add html into the page